# Oracle forms Installation Error - INST-07545

Tags: oracle, installation

In Oracle forms and reports
when I select oracle home to be

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home
```

I get

```
INST-07545: Unexpected Error. java.lang.NullPointerException
```

as shown :

[image]

Now here's another related issue

As an installation requirement I installed Oracle WebLogic Server 14c (14.1.1.0), but I cannot run it, as `startWebLogic.cmd` fails to start and here's the CMD result and the log file in the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/fido9dido/604dec2788416e9fbb9fe562b32d51e0).

**UPDATE:**
WebLogic installed 3  Domains  and none of them starts

```
wl_server 
medrec
medrec-spring
```

I Created new domain called base_domain and the new Domain Works

```
C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain
```

Oracle Forms and Reports Error changed after I changed the default temp location but the error changed

> INST-07548: The selected distribution does not have any compatible
> install type for the selected Oracle Home.
>
> INST-07551: Not all dependent featuresets for install type "Forms and
> Reports Deployment" could be found. The following prerequisites were
> found to be missing: em_fmc - 12.2.1.4.0wls_server - 12.2.1.4.0
> Select a different Oracle Home having all dependencies. Check
> http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=fmw122140&id=installhome
> for details about compatible products and install types.

Now I am using

```
JDK17
```

and the generic version of weblogic 608MB

```
fmw_14.1.1.0.0_wls_lite_generic.jar
```

and the latest oracle forms

```
setup_fmw_12.2.1.4.0_fr_win64.exe
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

The error say there's incompatibility error, but I am using the latest version of both from the following [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/12.2.1.4/mstrd/download-installation-and-configuration-readme.html#GUID-AF063205-BCB3-463C-A2D7-724420598544) which states:

**Oracle Forms and Reports**

Download the Oracle Fusion Middleware Infrastructure distribution from the [Oracle WebLogic Server download page](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/weblogic-server-installers-downloads.html).

Download the production distribution for Oracle Forms and Reports from the [Oracle Software Delivery Cloud](https://edelivery.oracle.com/osdc/faces/SoftwareDelivery).

Comment: Can you please point out what any of this has to do with database administration?

Comment: @mustaccio I did ask in the chat whether these kind of questions are appropriate on this forum and I was told yes plus [here's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=installation+oracle) similar questions on this site, if its not feel free to vote to close it

Comment: ok, @ma1169 is the problem with installing the Oracle DBMS (and if yes, which version of it), or with some other applications? (the questions mentions "Forms and Reports" and "Weblogic Server") And are these part of the Oracle DBMS or standalone installations?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ they are standalone installation, Oracle Forms and reports require oracle DBMS(I am using version 19c) and Oracle weblogic server and both dependencies works now, but still I cannot install the Forms

Comment: I found the solution to the problem, it is because I used the current latest version of oracle apps, oracle weblogic 14, and oracle forms 12, it seems their apps is not backward compatible, so i had to install weblogic 12 and it worked